# How to create a symbolic link from one user directory to anothers?

Tags: linux, symlink, access-control

I have 3 users: `admin` with sudo, and two normal users - `user1` and `user2`.

`user2` is under `user1` group.

There is a folder `fold1` as `/home/user1/fold1` which is under the group `user1` with read and write permissions.

Now I want to create a symbolic link to this above folder at a location
`/home/user2/fold1` so that `user2` can access and write the same folder.

All I have been trying is the following from the `admin` user:

```
su admin
sudo ln -s /home/user1/fold1 /home/user2/fold1
sudo chown user1:user1 /home/user2/fold1
```

I have also tried `sudo chown user2:user1 /home/user2/fold1`, but not working.

But anyway, `user2` cannot access this folder. Only a cross overlay is showing on the link from `user2` account.

What could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a soft link, `user2` will have to have access to the whole path of `/home/user1/fold1` with at least execution right (`x`).

(you should do a `chmod g+x /home/user1`)

Comment: The commands that I have put above, worked one time after repeated trials. But for some reasons I removed the link. And again now the same commands seem not to work. And there are already such shared other folders working.

Comment: can you past the result from `ls -l /home/ | grep user`, `ls -l /home/user1/ | grep fold` and `ls -l /home/user2/ | grep fold`  ?

Comment: from which account?

Comment: from any who can access those folder, for example the `admin` account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That `+x` to the group is the crux of the solution. And these `ls` commands were actually failing due to absence of `+x` permission from `user2` account.